# php rendering large zip file - memory limit reached

Tags: php, zip, rendering, memory-limit

I try to render a zip file in php. 
Code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
```

The downloaded file, is only few bytes. It is an error message:

`<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41908867 bytes) in <b>/var/www/common_index/main.php</b> on line <b>217</b><br />`

I do not wish to increase memory_limit in php.ini. What are alternative ways to properly render large zip files without tinkering with global settings?

Comment: Where is the zip file coming from? From disk or are you creating it on the fly? The basic solution is to stream the data so you don't hold it in memory all at the same time.

Comment: What function are you using to dump the file?  Have you looked into `readfile()`?  http://php.net/readfile

Answer (score 4):

Stream the download, so it doesn't choke on memory.
Tiny example:

```
$handle = fopen("exampe.zip", "rb");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    echo fread($handle, 1024);
    flush();
}
fclose($handle);
```

Add correct output headers for downloading, and you should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP actually provides an easy method to output a binary file directly to Apache without stashing it in memory first via the `readfile()` function:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
readfile('file.zip');
```