# Timing out on command line

Tags: php

I had previously asked a question, [and got the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278670/php-zip-include-only-new-files/18278926?noredirect=1#comment26814943_18278926), but I think I've run into another problem.

The php script I'm using does this:

1 - transfers a file to my server from my backup server

2 - when it's done transfering it sends some post data to it using curl, which creates a zip file

3 - when it's done, the result is echoed and depending on what the result is; transfers the file, or does nothing.

My problem is this:
When the file is small enough (under 500MB) it creates it, and transfers back no problem. When it's larger, it timesout, finishes creating the zip on the remote server, but because it timed out it doesn't get transfered.

I'm running this from a command line on the backup server. I have this in the php script:

```
set_time_limit(0);                   // ignore php timeout
ignore_user_abort(true);             // keep on going even if user pulls the plug*
while(ob_get_level())ob_end_clean(); // remove output buffers
```

But it still timesout when I run `sudo php backup.php`

Is using curl making it timeout like a browser on the other end where the zip is being made? I think the problem is the response isn't being echo'd out.

**Edits:
(@symcbean)**
I'm not seeing anything, which is why I'm struggling. When I run it from the browser, I see the loading thing in the address bar. After about 30 seconds it just stops. When I do it from the command line, same deal. 30 seconds and it just stops. This only happens when large zips need to be created.

It's being invoked via a file. The file loads a class, sends the connection information to the class. Which contacts the server to make the zip, transfers the zip back, does some stuff to it then transfers it to S3 for archiving.

It logs into the remote server, uploads a file with curl. upon a valid response, it curls again with the location of the file as a url (I'll always know what it is), which fires up the php file I just transfered over. The zip ALWAYS gets created no problem, even up to 22GB, just sometimes takes a long time of course. After that it waits for a response of "created". Waiting for that response is where it dies.

So the zip always gets created, but the waiting time is what "I think" is making it die.

**Second Edit:** 
I tried this from the command line:

```
$ftp_connect= ftp_connect('domain.com');
$ftp_login = ftp_login($ftp_connect,'user','pass'); 
ftp_pasv($ftp_connect, true);

$upload = ftp_put($ftp_connect, 'filelist.php', 'filelist.php', FTP_ASCII);

$get_remote = 'filelist.php';
$post_data = array (  
    'last_bu' => '0'
);      

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'domain.com/'.$get_remote);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );   
// adding the post variables to the request   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);   
//echo the following to get response 
$response = curl_exec($ch);     
curl_close($ch);    
echo $response;
```

and got this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>500 Internal Server Error</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.<P>
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred
and of anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.<P>
More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS>
Web Server at domain.com
</ADDRESS>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Again, the error log is blank, the zip still gets created, but because of the timeout around 650MB of creation I can't get the response.

Comment: I expect that sudo ask for a password in background. Replace that sudo stuff by giving the web server proper permissions

Comment: It's an amazon EC2 server. Running sudo just fires up the script, it doesn't wait for a response from the curl command. Using sudo, I believe, has nothing to do with that.

I tried it anyway, and it still times out on the command line not using sudo.

Comment: enter the command line and type: `su www-data` and then execute `sudo yourscript` ... does it ask for a password?

Comment: it does, and when I enter the password I get: `/usr/sbin/nologin: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Use `sudo su www-data`

Comment: What version of php are you using?
If 5.2.0 or low than you problem can be with safe_mode flag in php.ini.

Comment: version: 5.3.20 
using sudo su doesn't help either. still times out

Comment: From http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php:
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
What does 'php -i | grep safe' return?

Comment: safe_mode => Off => Off
safe_mode_exec_dir => no value => no value
safe_mode_gid => Off => Off
safe_mode_include_dir => no value => no value
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off

Comment: Hmm.
The only one suggestion is left. Could you try to add ini_set('max_execution_time', '0'); in php-file?

Comment: It's very unlikely to be your PHP script which is timing out - I've written daemons in PHP (with set_time_limit(0) which have happily run for weeks and only stopped when I told them too. Where are you seeing something which is telling you there is a timeout and what EXACTLY does it say? (also how are you *invoking* the script - via an sh session? Something else?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything, which is why I'm struggling. When I run it from the browser, I see the loading thing in the address bar. After about 30 seconds it just stops. When I do it from the command line, same deal. 30 seconds and it just stops.

It's being invoked via a file. The file has a loads a class, sends the connection information to the class. I'll copy and paste the code in the OP

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the server code that generates the file to be returned.

Check the php error log

It may be timing out for a few reasons but the log shouldl tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it guys, thank you so much to everyone who helped me, it pointed me in the right directions.

In the end, the problem was on the remote server. What was happening was that it was timing out the cURL connection, which didn't send the result I needed back.

What I did to fix it was add a function to my class that (again) using curl, checks for the zip file http code I know it's creating When it finishes, then throw the result locally. If it's not finished, sleep for a few seconds and check again.

```
private function watchDog(){

$curl = curl_init($this->host.'/'.$this->grab_file);

//don't fetch the actual page, you only want to check the connection is ok
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

//do request
$result = curl_exec($curl);

//if request did not fail
if ($result !== false) {
    //if request was ok, check response code
    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  

    if ($statusCode == 404) {
          sleep(7);
          self::watchDog();
    }
    else{
        return 'zip created'; 
    }
}

curl_close($curl);

}
```